# Bootstrap 4 beta - cols are not calculated correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm probably doing something really stupid but can't figure out what. I want something extremely simple. Divide page in two identical parts.

**Code looks like this:**

```
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            LEFT ONE
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            RIGHT ONE
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Problem:**

Despite the fact it divides the page in two parts, it also makes some overflow on X line. I tried to find the reason and noticed that if I count both that `<div class="col-lg-6">` it has a slightly bigger width than parent `<div class="row">`.

**Snippet:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            LEFT ONE
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            RIGHT ONE
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Your snippet seems to work on my browser (latest Chrome). Note that `col-lg` requires window width of at least 992 pixels in order to be placed on the same line - maybe your browser window is just too narrow? Try changing the column classes to `col-sm-6` or `col-xs-6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forget to put `container`or `container-fluid` class.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            LEFT ONE
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            RIGHT ONE
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I found `container` in some tutorials but it wasn't what I was looking for because of huge margin on sites. But `container-fluid` do the right job. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            LEFT ONE
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            RIGHT ONE
        </div>
</div>
```